# Magnetic field caused by 2 rings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetostatics

Two rings are placed parallel atop each other along an axis with a distance $\epsilon$ which is much smaller than the radius of both rings R. Through one of the rings there is a current I and through the other the same current but in the opposite direction. Exactly between the rings along the axis the magnetic field is zero and at points far away as well, so there must be a point along the axis between 0 and ∞ where the magnetic field is at a maximum. You can use $\epsilon << R$

I started by adding the the magnetic fields together:

$$ B(z) = \frac{\mu IR²}{2} \left(\frac{1}{(R²+(z-\frac{\epsilon}{2})²)^{3/2}}-\frac{1}{(R²+(z+\frac{\epsilon}{2})²)^{3/2}}\right) $$

Then I tried to find the maximum by differentiating B and making it equal to 0. This gives the following equation:

$$ B´(z) = \frac{-3\mu IR²}{2} \left(\frac{z-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{(R²+(z-\frac{\epsilon}{2})²)^{5/2}}-\frac{z+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{(R²+(z+\frac{\epsilon}{2})²)^{5/2}}\right) = 0 $$

$$ \frac{z-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{z+\frac{\epsilon}{2}} = \frac{(R²+(z-\frac{\epsilon}{2})²)^{5/2}}{(R²+(z+\frac{\epsilon}{2})²)^{5/2}} $$

I tried to solve for z but the equation is too complex. I suspect I need to use $\epsilon<<R$ to make a Taylor expansion but I am totally lost.

Do you have any tips so I can move forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path - you just seem to be stuck with your Taylor expansion.

I suggest that you cross multiply your expressions (so you get rid of the large fractions), then note that 
$$R^2 + \left(z-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)^2=\\
R^2+z^2-\epsilon z + \frac14\epsilon^2$$
Now we know that $\epsilon << R$ but we don't know how small $z$ will turn out to be; so we reorganize the expression to

$$\left(R^2+z^2\right)\left(1 - \frac{\epsilon z}{R^2+z^2}+\frac{\epsilon^2}{4\left(R^2+z^2\right)}\right)$$

If you now do a Taylor expansion, I think you will find that you only need to keep the first ($\epsilon z$ containing) term... Obviously you have to be careful of signs etc.

Comment: That helps a lot! Is it smart to do the taylor expansion with the power (5/2) as well?

Comment: Good to hear it. Let me know if you can now solve it.

Comment: Incidentally it will be easier to take the entire expression to the $\frac25^{th}$ power - then the only thing you need to expand is $\left(z±\epsilon/2\right)^{2/5}$ which is easier than the "big" thing to the power $\frac52$. Note you will need to carry at least two terms because the first order terms look like they will cancel...